# How do I avoid recursive object fetching with C# and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Right now, for accessing all child categories of a self joining object I am making query like this.

```
var productCategories = db.Categories.Inlcude("ChildCategories")
            .Inlcude("ChildCategories.ChildCategories")
            .Inlcude("ChildCategories.ChildCategories.ChildCategories")
            .Inlcude("ChildCategories.ChildCategories.ChildCategories.ChildCategories")
            .Inlcude("ChildCategories.ChildCategories.ChildCategories.ChildCategories.ChildCategories")
            .Inlcude("ChildCategories.ChildCategories.ChildCategories.ChildCategories.ChildCategories.ChildCategories")
```

What can be done to about this kind of query?

Comment: Well possibly a db.Categories.ToList() will do, because it will fetch all Categories. But i have to admit, i have no idea how to do this, if you need a where() ...

Answer (score 1):

To allow the IQueryable to fetch everything (opposite of Lazy Loading), you can disable Lazy Loading on the DBContext.

```
 using(DBContext db = new DBContext) {
      db.ContextOptions.LaxyLoadingEnabled = false;
      // TODO: Other code here
 }
```

Edit: Fixed answer in response to @Slauma comment.

In the case that ChildCategory is a child class of Category (inheritance):

If you want the IQueryable to fetch everything for a `ChildCategory`, you can use the `OfType<T>()` method.

```
 var productCategories = db.Categories.OfType<ChildCategories>();
```

Comment: Why `OfType`? It is for filtering derived entities, but `ChildCategories` is a navigation collection of the same type as `Category`, nothing is derived here.

Comment: @Slauma Right, my mistake, when I see the word Child, I think inheritance.